# Change opacity of DynamicMapsEngineLayer, not just a single feature

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

From the Google Maps API, I see the `getFeatureStyle` function, but that requires you to pass in a feature ID. I want to change the fill/stroke opacity of the whole layer. Is this possible?

Was looking here, and tried to play around with the layer object, the only interesting functions were the `set/get`, which I think set arbitrary properties. Apart from that I see no way to do that, or even loop through all the features to toggle each one, which would be slow..

Here's the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DynamicMapsEngineLayer).

Comment: I'm with you, @Knownasilya. We're looking for [similar things](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789669/google-maps-api-and-dynamicmapsenginelayer-loop-over-features-in-the-map). The way I see it, the `DynamicMapsEngineLayer` renders features in the client, so they have to be there somewhere. Right?

Comment: Looks like there really is no way at the moment, but improvements are sure to come for GME integration with GMaps.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to change the attributes of the entire layer at once.  However, you can just iterate through all the features, which is pretty fast; I've got an app (not public yet, alas) that changes the appearance of 50+ very complicated coastline polygons at once, and the change is pretty much instant.

The other option would be to use [GeoJSON](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/maps-made-easier-geojson-in-the-javascript-maps-api.html), in particular the [declarative style rules](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#declarative_style_rules); then you can just change the values in the JSON and the display will update accordingly.  You can read [GeoJSON directly from the Maps Engine API](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/combining-data).

Comment: In relation to GME, GeoJSON does not apply, also iterating over the features is fine, as long as you have a small amount. It's not as realistic for 1000+ features.

Comment: Hmm?  You can read GME data into GeoJSON for rendering, see the link and demo above.